# Treemap with <Integer, List>

Tags: java, list, treemap

I'm going count the most used words in a text and I want to make it this way just need little help how i'm gonna fix the Treemap.. 
this is how its look like now ...

```
    TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> Word = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    List<String> TheList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

//While there is still something to read..

```
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String NewWord = scanner.next().toLowerCase();

        if (Word.containsKey(NewWord)) {
            Word.put(HERE I NEED HELP);
        } else {
            Word.put(HERE I NEED HELP);
        }

    }
```

So what i wanna do is if the NewWord is in the list then add one on Integer(key) and if not Add the word to the next list.

Comment: You do realise that word length cannot be <0 or >N where N is pretty small.  You could use an ArrayList instead of a Map.

Answer (score 1):

Your type appears to be completely incorrect

... if you want a frequency count

You want to have your word as the key and the count as the value.  There is little value in using a sorted collection, but it is many time slower so I would use a HashMap.

```
Map<String, Integer> frequencyCount = new HashMap<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
    Integer count = frequencyCount.get(word);
    if (count == null)
        frequencyCount.put(word, 1);
    else
        frequencyCount.put(word, 1 + count);
}
```

---

... if you want to key by length.  I would use a `List<Set<String>>`  This is because your word length is positive and bounded, and you want to ignore duplicate words which is something a Set is designed to do.

```
 List<Set<String>> wordsByLength = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
    // grow the array list as required.
    while(wordsByteLength.size() <= word.length()) 
         wordsByLength.add(new HashSet<String>());
    // add the word ignoring duplicates.
    wordsByLength.get(words.length()).add(word);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

All the examples above are correctly storing the count into a map, unfortunately they are not sorting by count which is a requirement you also have.

Do not use a TreeMap, instead use a HashMap to build up the values.

Once you have the complete list of values built you can then drop the `entrySet` from the HashMap into a new `ArrayList` and sort that array list by `Entry<String,Integer>.getValue()`.

Or to be neater create a new "Count" object which has both the word and the count in and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do..

```
  TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>
```

instead do,

```
 TreeMap<String, Integer>   // String represents the word... Integer represents the count
```

because your key (count) can be same sometimes where as the words will be unique... 
Do it the other way around... keep reading the  words and check if your map contains that word... If yes, increment the count, else add the word with count = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> Word = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String NewWord = scanner.next().toLowerCase();

    if (Word.containsKey(NewWord)) {
        Word.put(NewWord,Word.get(NewWord)+1);
    } else {
        Word.put(NewWord,1);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Prabhakaran: Changed ;)

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this in a time-efficient manner is to have *two* maps. One map should be from keys to counts, and the other from counts to keys. You can assemble these in different passes. The first should assemble the map from keys to counts:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
    wordCount.put(word, wordCount.containsKey(word) ? wordCount.get(word) + 1 : 1);
}
```

The second phase *inverts* the map so that you can read off the top-most keys:

```
// Biggest values first!
Map<Integer,List<String>> wordsByFreq = new TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a - b;
    }
});
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : wordCount) {
    List<String> current = wordsByFreq.get(e.getValue());
    if (current == null)
        wordsByFreq.put(e.getValue(), current = new ArrayList<String>());
    current.add(e.getKey());
}
```

Note that the first stage uses a HashMap because we don't need the order at all; just speedy access. The second stage needs a TreeMap and it needs a non-standard comparator so that the first value read out will be the list of most-frequent words (allowing for two or more words to be most-frequent).

Comment: Yes, this would work. The second Map is overkill unless he needs a dynamic count though.

Comment: The cost of using a TreeMap to sort is asymptotically equivalent to a good sort, and does relieve the programmer from having to cook up so many classes themselves. (It's also closer to where they started from.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
        TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = null;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String NewWord = scanner.next().toLowerCase();

            if (map.containsKey(NewWord)) {
                Integer count = map.get(NewWord);
                // Add the element back along with incremented count
                map.put(NewWord, count++); 
            } else {
                map.put(NewWord,1); // Add a new entry
            }

        }
```

Comment: He's using a treemap in order to sort the results by count, this will not do that.

Comment: @TimB - Then he must be adding the words of the same length to the list (value) of the map for each count... But what makes more sense is if he uses a hashmap (yes.. I saw your answer... and you are right... )